# Windows - Can't delete / get rid of a file on a damaged cluster

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, chkdsk

My laptop started to do a CheckDisk/CHKDSK every boot, and after some investigations, I found the culprits : some files on damaged clusters.

With a little bit of perserverance, I finally managed to delete those (kill a lot of process, and use Unlocker to do the deletion).

Now I can't even see the files, but the are still on the disk and on damaged clusters.

Screenshot of my last CHKDSK (pardon my french) `chkdsk d: /r /f` :
[image: Screenshot of my last CHKDSK]

The highlighted part says (for 2 files) :

> Insuficient disk space to replace damaged clusters detected in file 3365Xxx named \$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-~....

But I have more almost 70% of free space on that disk, so that should be a problem...

I've tried to display the files in Windows Explorer but I can only get into the folder, I can't see the files.

With `cmd`, I've tried to delete the folders in the RECYCLE.BIN :

```
C:\Windows\system32>rd /s /q D:\$Recycle.bin
D:\$Recycle.bin\S-1-5-~1 - Directory isn't empty
```

So I've tried to get into the folder and delete it directly :

```
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1143489171-773386741-1919468805-1001>del $RB6F7O8.mp4
```

Which raise a bubble alert from windows saying that the file is damaged and to do a CHKDSK (which didn't correct anything).

So I tried to force it :

```
D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1143489171-773386741-1919468805-1001>del /f /s $RB6F7O8.mp4
```

Which returned (translated) :

> File deleted - D:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-1143489171-773386741-1919468805-1001\$RB6F7O8.mp4

But throw another bubble alert from windows :
[image: Exception processing message 0xc0000102 Parameters]

And I can't think of what to try next to get rid of the files on those clusters, to avoid CHKDSK every boot.

(I've thought about a `.bat` to manually ask windows not to perform the CHKDSK and turn off computer, but I don't really like the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Backup your data.
2. Boot ubuntu livecd or [gparted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) livecd.
3. Mount damaged volume.
4. rm -r /mnt/damaged_volume/$RECYCLE.BIN
5. reboot to windows
6. chkdsk /F /X D:
7. reboot

and also I'd recommend to boot livecd and make full antivirus scan.

Comment: Thx ! Only needed to switch to Linux and it was deleted in a second ! I used a Linux Mint bootable key (made with Rufus), and I didn't have to type a single line to get this done !^^

Comment: Glad it resolved.