# Delete Windows $RECYCLE.BIN folder from Linux

Tags: linux, windows

I mounted a hard drive which was used by Windows on a Linux Machine, Raspberry Pi to be exact.

Trying to delete the recycle bin folder throws this error:

```
$ rm "$RECYCLE.BIN"
rm: cannot remove '.BIN': No such file or directory
```

What's the correct way to remove such folder?

Comment: @harrymc Hidden Windows file is not the same thing as "dotfile" in Linux though. Besides, it's a directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is that bash, the command shell you are using, interprets any text following a $ as an environmental variable. You can see this if you type the command:

```
echo $PWD
#outputs on my system: /home/chris
```

^On most linux systems this prints the variable that describes the present working directory.

When you use double quotes in a bash expression this tells bash in effect *'I want you to interpret everything inside these normally'* which in your case means converting environmental variables to their associated values. Since I imagine your environmental for $RECYCLE is not set to anything the value is a zero length string. Therefore the result of your quoted expression is ".BIN". Since .BIN is not a valid file or directory rm will complain.

The correct solution is in bash you want to use single quotes ' around these expressions. This will tell bash to not do environmental variable expansion or other expansions and send the containing text **exactly as it appears** to the command.

With all that in mind your correct command line expression would be:

```
rm '$RECYCLE.BIN'
```

Also on another side note rm will probably still complain because if I remember correctly $RECYCLE.BIN is a directory. Without the -r command line option it will say that rm cannot remove the directory.

To read up on more bash/rm/environment variables details type in your console:

```
man bash
man rm
man environment
```

Comment: Yes, [-r](https://superuser.com/questions/1545259/windows-cant-delete-get-rid-of-a-file-on-a-damaged-cluster) will indeed be required.